# Получение текста в кавычках

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть данные вида: `{'id': '3', 'answer': '1'},{'id': '4', 'answer': 'здесь ответ на вопрос, 12345 abc'},{'id': '4', 'answer': '123'}`.
Нужно получить текст в кавычках после " 'answer': ", в регулярки могу не особо, получилось что-то вроде `/'answer':.['](\W+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\S+\s\w+)|:.'(\w+)[']}/`, с таким выражением бывает что не выдергивается значение целиком (если после 12345 abc добавить еще один пробел регулярка уже ломается), или вообще ничего не выдергивается. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно составить регулярку для этого.

Comment: Это [джсон](https://www.json.org/json-ru.html). `json_decode` в помощь.

Comment: Какой должен быть результат?

Comment: Нужно получить всё, что в кавычках после answer. Через json_decode пробовал, получается текстовый массив.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/XiiIA?

Comment: Да, то что нужно, спасибо

Comment: Ну и обойди этот текстовый массив и в ключе `answer` будет то что надо. Вместо простого цикла будешь потом пытаться понять что делает эта регулярка.

Comment: Так в массиве у всех записей тип string а не object, я пытался через цикл сначала прогнать, получил illegal offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно конвертировать вашу строку в валидный JSON. Сначала преобразуем одиночные кавчки в двойные.

Это можно сделать с помощью [следующей функции](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348380):

```
function fixJSON($json) {
    $regex = <<<'REGEX'
~
    "[^"\\]*(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)*"
    (*SKIP)(*F)
  | '([^'\\]*(?:\\.|[^'\\]*)*)'
~x
REGEX;

    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {
        return '"' . preg_replace('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(*F)|"~', '\\"', $matches[1]) . '"';
    }, $json);
}
```

Чтобы строка распарсилась как надо, после преобразования заключим строку в квадратные скобки и используем функцию [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php):

```
$json = "{'id': '3', 'answer': '1'},{'id': '4', 'answer': 'здесь ответ на вопрос, 12345 abc'},{'id': '4', 'answer': '123'}";   // Задаём нашу строку
$obj = json_decode(fixJSON("[$json]"));  // Получаем объект JSON
```

Далее остаётся пройтись по всем элементам и получить значения в ключах со значением `answer`:

```
foreach ($obj as $key=>$val) {
  echo "$val->answer\n";
}
// => 1   
// => здесь ответ на вопрос, 12345 abc
// => 123
```

См. [пример работы кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/YhZNp).

Comment: Пришлось накинуть костыль для входных данных, но с ним работает нормально.
`$json = json_decode(fixJSON("$answers"));
$json = implode(",",$json);
$obj = json_decode(fixJSON("[$json]"));
foreach ($obj as $key=>$val) {
  echo ($val->answer."<br>");
}`